# Removing columns from meta.data in Seurat

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to remove columns from the meta.data from a Seurat object. Is there a way to do that or would I have to re-create the Seurat object without that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the column you don't want to NULL

```
x$remove.column <- NULL
```